# List of cards doesnt change after deletion of any card without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

`I have the page that shows list of movies saved by user. User can delete his saved movies. Pressing the button deletes the movie from server and should remove the card from the list, but in my case it disappears from the list only after refreshing the page. The project is made on React.js.

I have several components: App, SavedMovies, MoviesCardList, MoviesCard:
-App is main component
-SavedMovies - component that shows movies saved by user
-MoviesCardList - section with cards
-MoviesCard - movie-card

I cant figure out why doesnt the SavedMovies update after delete without refreshing. Detele fetch works fine.
Here are parts of the components:`

```
function App() {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false);
  const [savedMovies, setSavedMovies] = useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      Promise.all([mainApi.getUserInfo(), mainApi.getSavedMovies()])
        .then(([data, items]) => {
          const saved = items.filter((m) => m.owner === data._id);

          setCurrentUser(data);
          setSavedMovies(saved);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn])

  function handleDeleteMovie(movie) {
    const savedMovie = savedMovies.find((m) => {
      return m.movieId === (movie.id || movie.movieId)
    })
    const newSavedMovies = savedMovies.filter((m) => m.movieId !== movie.id)

    mainApi.deleteMovie(savedMovie._id)
      .then(() => {
        setSavedMovies(newSavedMovies);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="saved-movies" element={
            <ProtectedRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
              <Header isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
              <SavedMovies
                savedMovies={savedMovies}
                onDeleteMovie={handleDeleteMovie}
              />
              <Footer />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          } />
        </Routes>
      </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

function SavedMovies({ savedMovies, onDeleteMovie }) {
  const [isShortChecked, setIsShortChecked] = useState(false);
  const [initialMovies, setInitialMovies] = useState(savedMovies);
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState(initialMovies);

  function filterShortMovies(movies) {
    return movies.filter((movie) =>
      movie.duration <= 40
    )
  }

  function handleFilter(query) {
    const result = savedMovies.filter((movie) => {
      return (
        movie.nameRU.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
        movie.nameEN.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
      )
    })
    setInitialMovies(result);
    setSearchResult(isShortChecked ? filterShortMovies(result) : result);
  }

  function handleShort() {
    setIsShortChecked(!isShortChecked);
    if (!isShortChecked) {
      setSearchResult(filterShortMovies(initialMovies))
    } else {
      setSearchResult(initialMovies)
    }
  }

  function onSearchSubmit(inputData) {
    handleFilter(inputData)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResult(savedMovies)
  }, [savedMovies])

  return (
    <div className='saved-movies'>
      <SearchForm
        onSearch={onSearchSubmit}
        isShort={isShortChecked}
        handleShort={handleShort} />
      <MoviesCardList
        savedMovies={savedMovies}
        onDeleteMovie={onDeleteMovie}
        movies={searchResult}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

function MoviesCard({ movie, onSaveMovie, onDeleteMovie, isSaved }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = React.useState('');
  const [buttonClassName, setButtonClassName] = React.useState('');
  const [buttonVisibility, setButtonVisibility] = React.useState('movie-card__button_invisible');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSaved) {
      setButtonText('');
      setButtonClassName('movie-card__button-delete');
      setButtonVisibility('');
      if (location.pathname === '/saved-movies') {
        setButtonVisibility('movie-card__button_invisible');
      }
    } else {
      setButtonText('Сохранить');
      setButtonClassName('movie-card__button-save');
      setButtonVisibility('movie-card__button_invisible');
    }
  }, [isSaved]
  )

  function handleButtonChange(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (isSaved) {
      onDeleteMovie(movie);
      setButtonClassName('movie-card__button-save');
      setButtonText('Сохранить');
    } else {
      onSaveMovie(movie);
      setButtonText('');
      setButtonClassName('movie-card__button-delete');
    }
  }

  function handleDelete(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    onDeleteMovie(movie);
  }

  return (
    <div className='movie-card'>
      <a href={movie.trailerLink} className='movie-card__container' onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={ } className='movie-card__image' />
        {
          location.pathname === '/saved-movies' && (
            <button className={`movie-card__button movie-card__button-remove ${buttonVisibility}`} onClick={handleDelete}></button>
          )
        }
      </a>
      <div className='movie-card__description'>
        <p className='movie-card__name'>{movie.name}</p>
        <span className='movie-card__duration'>{`${hours} ${minutes}`}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried to disable cache, added useEffect hook in SavedMovies component that watches for changes in savedMovies state but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `setSavedMovies` like so:

```js
mainApi.deleteMovie(savedMovie._id)
  .then(() => {
    setSavedMovies(_savedMovies => _savedMovies.filter((m) => m._id !== movie._id));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

And if that doesn't work, add a `console.log` before `setSavedMovies` make sure it's actually executing.

Comment: Console.log works, but this didnt help still

Comment: I tried to console.log(savedMovies) before and after setSavedMovies, and it shows the same array, but inspite of that the useEffect(()=> {...}, [savedMovies]) executes but doesnt update anything

Comment: @Rubyroido Can you show what the output of `savedMovie` is and `movie`?

Comment: savedMovie is an object with information about the movie the user clicked to delete. Console.log showed the same object because only saved movies have '_id' key:
savedMovie: _id:"6465ce7cf01567a795b85d5c"
movie: _id: _id:"6465ce7cf01567a795b85d5c"

Comment: then why is this condition different? `m.movieId !== movie.id` why are you using two different keys? try `m._id !== movie._id`

Comment: There are two apis. One with the list of all films, and another with user information and saved films. Also there is another route for all movies fetched from the first api where user can save and delete movies, so this check works there. And here in SavedMovies component are only movies fetched from the second api.

Comment: Facepalm, thank you so much, this check was really a reason